# Liferay Developer Studio not showing "File" menu, any trick to perform an import?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-13.10, liferay-ide

For some reason [Liferay Developer Studio](https://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide) (Eclipse-based) does not show the `File` menu:

[image]

As you can see, just a 1-pixel-high menu appears.
For comparizon, the `Edit` menu shows correctly:

[image]

In these condition, how can I invoke the `Import` item which is supposed to be found under `New`?

Is there any shortcut?
Or maybe a way to call actions via command line or IPC or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
Instead of running `./LiferayDeveloperStudio`, run `./fix-menu.sh`

This way, the menu appears correctly:

[image]

What it does is set an environment variable like this then call LiferayDeveloperStudio:

```
env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 && ./LiferayDeveloperStudio
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution.

On liferay studio 2.0.0, there is a file named fix-menu.sh that has a bug, but changing his content for this:

## !/bin/sh

UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 && ./DeveloperStudio

solve the problem too.

Regards.